# Insert a video at beginning of a current youtube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to see if the YouTube API supports inserting a video into a current YouTube video.  This can manually be accomplished via the YouTube editor.  However, I am looking to do this for all videos within a channel via an API call.  Is this possible?

Thank you so much.

Comment: AFAIK, even manually you can only create new videos by combining clips from existing ones. You can't actually edit an existing video in the sense that it will keep its ID and statistics.

Comment: Thank you, Paolo.  I believe you are right.  I thought the enhancements tab would allow that, but it only allows trimming.